# How to Embedded JQuery code in a php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to embedded the below jquery code in the following php variable $var

JQUERY Code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#jQueryDialog1').dialog('open');return false;"><img src="images/image.png" id="Image1" alt="" style="width:30px;height:30px;"></a>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php $var = 'my_jquery_code'; return $var; ?>
```

Comment: don't use `onclick` and problem goes away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to escape the single quotes:

```
<?php
$var ='<a href="#" onclick="$(\'#jQueryDialog1\').dialog(\'open\');return false;"><img src="images/image.png" id="Image1" alt="" style="width:30px;height:30px;"></a>';
return $var;
```

Comment: Or use double quotes instead single quotes

Comment: In that case you'd have to escape the double quotes

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable scenario I can think of where you would want to use onclick would be if you're dynamically loading the anchor element.

If so, this is probably better.

```
[script]
  $(document).on('click', '.my_class_here', function() {
    $('jQueryDialog1').dialog('open');
  });
[/script]

[link_template]
  <a href="#" class="my_class_here">...</a>
[/link_template]
```

Then you would use AJAX or whatever voodoo you like to retrieve the link template (maybe while passing it some variables?) and add it to the page.

Alternatively, you can use `$(document).find('.my_class_here').on('click', function...` , but this is bad, performance wise.

Comment: Thank you Alex for this precious idea that's a professional code from a professional coder :)